# Working with oldest datetimes for multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

My table contains 10 datetime columns (`item1` - `item10`), which represent 10 services offered by my members. In any given "city/county" there are only 12 positions available for each of 10 services. Basically, I need the twelve oldest datetimes from each column to be returned respectively as "item1", "item2", "item3", etc., and else as "".

The item#'s are echoed into member's listing, where I use jquery to filter the listings.

My current code sets a limit, but not according to datetime. The problem shows up if all positions on a page are filled. A senior member can then "bump" newer members off if they decide to offer additional services.

In case I'm not explaining this well, here's a working example: 
http://integritycontractingofva.com/pest_control/Richmond_VA.php

```
$result = @mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE category LIKE '%$category%' AND territories LIKE '%$area.%' AND exp >= NOW()");
if (!$result){echo ("<p>Error performing listing query:" . mysql_error() . "</p>");}

$item1cnt = $item2cnt = $item3cnt = $item4cnt = $item5cnt = $item6cnt = $item7cnt = $item8cnt = $item9cnt = $item10cnt = 0;   //start counter at "0"
$items = array();
$today = date('Y-m-d');
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if($row["exp"] > $today){

      if($row["item1"]!="0000-00-00 00:00:00"){ // if datetime is set
        $item1cnt++;                            // add one to counter
        if($item1cnt > 12){                     // if counter is greater than 12
          $row["item1"]="";                     // itemx = ""
        }else{                                  // if counter is less than 12
          $row["item1"]="item1";                // item = itemx
        }
      }else{                                    // if datetime is not set
          $row["item1"]="";                     // itemx = ""
       }

// repeat above for all 10 items


// part of member's listing used by jquery to filter services
  $items[] = "<li class=\"services " . $row["item1"] . " " . $row["item2"] . " " . $row["item3"] . " " . $row["item4"] . " " . $row["item5"] . " " . $row["item6"] . " " . $row["item7"] . " " . $row["item8"] . " " . $row["item9"] . " " . $row["item10"] . "\">";

  }
}
```

If a member has datetime set for `item1`, `item3`, and `item9`, the printed result would be `<li class="services item1 item3 item9">`

Comment: Oh man, do you mind to format your code more nicely to make it more readable?

Comment: I guess this should be done in pure MySQL somehow not iterating through ALL records of table. To give you idea change your SQL to select last 10 (items) * 12 (entities) = max 120 records only like this `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ... ORDER BY item1 desc, item2 desc, ..., item10 desc LIMIT 120;` This way you at least will cut your fetching to max 120 records.

Comment: I've edited the code for clarity. I like your idea to add LIMIT.

Comment: And add `WHERE exp>NOW()` (only not expired licences as I understood) in SQL and you don't have to do that in PHP. PHP should receive only necessary data records no less no more.

Comment: I am currently using `WHERE exp>NOW()`, which represents expiration of registered listings.

Comment: so you don't need this line `if($row["exp"] > $today)`

Comment: Dangit Darkside!! lol... I need to get in the habit of checking/revising my codes as I make changes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this will work and not sure about performance, but you can try something like this.

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    CONCAT_WS(' ',
        a1.class,
        a2.class,
        ...
        a10.class
    ) AS class
FROM table t
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT id,'item1' AS class FROM table ORDER BY item1 desc LIMIT 12) a1 ON t.id=a1.id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT id,'item2' AS class FROM table ORDER BY item2 desc LIMIT 12) a2 ON t.id=a2.id
    ...
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT id,'item10' AS class FROM table ORDER BY item10 desc LIMIT 12) a10 ON t.id=a10.id
```

---

and all of this

```
if($row["item1"]!="0000-00-00 00:00:00"){ // if datetime is set
    $item1cnt++;                          // add one to counter
    if($item1cnt > 12){                   // if counter is greater than 12
        $row["item1"]="";                 // itemx = ""
    }else{                                // if counter is less than 12
        $row["item1"]="item1";            // item = itemx
    }
}else{                                    // if datetime is not set
    $row["item1"]="";                     // itemx = ""
}
// repeat above for all 10 items
```

can be written simply like this (for all 10 elements):

```
// config
$item_count = 10;
$show_records = 12;
// process
$cnt = array_fill(1, $item_count, 0);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $item_count; $i++) {
    $n = "item" . $i;
    if (!$row[$n] || $row[$n] === "0000-00-00 00:00:00" || $cnt[$i] >= $show_records) {
        $row[$n] = "";
    } else {
        $cnt[$n]++;
    }
}
```

---

**Final solution:**

```
// === SELECTING ===
$result = mysqli_query($db, "
    SELECT
        t.*,
        CONCAT_WS(' ',
            a1.class,
            a2.class,
            ...
            a10.class
        ) AS classes
    FROM table t
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT id,'item1' AS class FROM table ORDER BY item1 desc LIMIT 12) a1 ON t.id=a1.id
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT id,'item2' AS class FROM table ORDER BY item2 desc LIMIT 12) a2 ON t.id=a2.id
        ...
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT id,'item10' AS class FROM table ORDER BY item10 desc LIMIT 12) a10 ON t.id=a10.id
    WHERE
        t.category LIKE '%$category%'
        AND t.territories LIKE '%$area.%'
        AND t.exp >= NOW()    
");
if (!$result){
    echo ("<p>Error performing listing query:" . mysql_error() . "</p>");
    exit;
}

// === PARSING ===

// config
$item_count = 10;
$show_records = 12;
// process
$cnt = array_fill(1, $item_count, 0);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $item_count; $i++) {
    $n = "item" . $i;
    if (!$row[$n] || $row[$n] === "0000-00-00 00:00:00" || $cnt[$i] >= $show_records) {
        $row[$n] = "";
    } else {
        $cnt[$n]++;
    }
}

// part of member's listing used by jquery to filter services
$items[] = '<li class="services ' . $row['classes'] . '">';
```

P.S. You should properly escape `$category` and `$area` if it's user input before injecting them in SQL query. This can be done with `mysql_real_escape`.

Comment: I will toy around with this within the next few days... when my brain begins to fire again!!! It would be nice to get this working using the query, rather than manipulating the results :)

Comment: Plus one for array_fill, and the exceptional simplification! Now I'm wondering if each column (`itemx`) datetimes can be placed into an array, giving value of respective "itemx" to the oldest 12, and  others a value of " ", then using the modified arrays in the while loop to create the listing.

Comment: Not sure what you want to accomplish with that. Get oldest dates? Then just exchange `ORDER BY` to `asc` and ... that's it.

Comment: Simply, to make each `itemx` (services) with the 12 oldest dates  searchable, using tags for the respective members. So there is "senority" with the services, rather than the members... Kind of a first-come, first-serve idea for each of the services. I swear it's much clearer in my head!

Comment: I hope so :) Just use `ORDER asc` instead of `ORDER desc`

Comment: How/where do I combine your code with my original query?... in order to select other columns like `firstname`, `lastname`, `startdate`, etc. and keep the `WHERE` clause in tact to filter the listings according to `category`, `area`, and `exp`? I'm not very familiar with `LEFT JOIN`, except for extremely simple examples.

Comment: OK, I can't teach you everything here, but see my last edit - final solution. I didn't test it, but that's how it should work.

Comment: Thank you @DarkSide for your final solution. I still couldn't get it working. The only thing I got was "Error performing listing query". The page loads (with listings) if I omit the `CONCAT_WS` and `LEFT JOIN` statements... of course, which is an abbreviated version of the original code. It's probably something simple I'm missing :) Thanks again for your time and effort!

Comment: maybe that dot after `$area.`? Anyway returned rows shouldn't depend on usage of LEFT JOIN or CONCAT_WS. Probably there's some MySQL error. Try debugging with `mysql_error()` and see your log files.

Comment: if please accept my answer if that solves your issues or at least is very close to that :)

Comment: P.S. - I use `mysql_error()` and nothing new is in the file.

Comment: I got the counter working (partly). I changed the else statement from $cnt[$n]++; to $row[$n] = $n;. $item_count works, but $show_records does not. I set $show_records to 2 on this page: integritycontractingofva.com/pest_control/a_test_VA.php. If you click the blue "view Listings" button, and then "Indoor Bugs" from the left menu, all 4 listings show.

Comment: of course it'll not work that way. $cnt[$n]++ should stay where it is. Look, we can't help you to write all your scripts. This site is only to answer specific questions not solve all and every issue :)

Comment: Although it would be nice, I'm not looking to have my scripts written:) My previous comment was describing what I had to do to get the script to work partially. It wasn't working at all before changing`$cnt[$n]++` to `$row[$n]`. So as not to waste time (yours or mine) I will just leave my original code as is. Since it limits the members, that will buy me a little time for now. Hopefully I can figure out how to limit each service as well:) I have accepted your answer for your efforts, and the fact that I learned from your responses.

Comment: Finally got it! :D @DarkSide, I had to use a `WHERE` clause to within each `LEFT JOIN` like:
`LEFT JOIN (SELECT account, 'item1' AS class FROM table WHERE item1!='0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND category LIKE '%$category%' AND territories LIKE '%$area.%' AND exp >= NOW() AND start !='0000-00-00' ORDER BY item1 asc LIMIT 12) a1 ON t.account=a1.account`. Best part is, by using `LIMIT` I no longer need a counter. The "only thing" I don't get... Is it the `AS Classes` which causes the datetimes to change to the approriate column names (i.e. from "2014-06-07 22:22:22" to "item1")?

Comment: `(...) AS classes` will define alias for your calculated "column", so you can get its value by `$row['classes']`.

Comment: And YES you're absolutely right, you need to extend `WHERE` clause in joined tables too. I somehow missed that.

Comment: `'somestring' AS class` doesn't change datetime to column name or something. It simply assigns constant string value `'somestring'` to alias `class`. That's all.

Comment: I removed the "config" and "process" from code and it still converts the datetimes like "<li class="services item1 item4">" :) It'll have to remain a mystery! One last thought... For the sake of speed, how to create a reduced table with `WHERE category LIKE '%$category%' AND territories LIKE %$area.%' AND exp >= NOW()` so that the entire table doesn't have to be scanned for each of the ten items... and so `LEFT JOIN`'s `WHERE` clause could be reduced to " item1!='0000-00-00 00:00:00'"

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. WHERE clause is already in SQL and you don't need additional PHP scanning/parsing. Man, you really need to think about your solution with "cold head". What is what you really want, what results your SQL gives, what you need in PHP to convert results your get from MySQL into visual presentation needed.

Comment: What I wanted to do has been accomplished, using your code. It seems like the is scanning the entire `table` for each of the ten `item` columns, and so I wondered if there was a way to scan only `table t`, since the number of rows has already been reduced by selecting category, exp, start, and territories. I was just concerned that scanning `table` multiple times would become much slower as the number of rows increased. That's all. Thanks for your patience, and all of your help!