# Replace newest n datetimes in array

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to replace all datetime values in an array from a MYSQLi query that are not the oldest 2. I've tried getting the results with the query, but it seems too complex since I need to do this for multiple columns. Is there a way to do this with PHP?

So if:

```
$row["item"] =
"2014-01-01 00:00:00 2014-04-04 00:00:00 2014-02-02 00:00:00 2014-03-03 00:00:00"
```

Return:

```
$row["item"] = 
"2014-01-01 00:00:00 new 2014-02-02 00:00:00 new"
```

**Update**

My apologies, I may be mistaken... if my member's listings are created within a `while` loop, is an array even returned, or is one `$row["item1"], $row["item2"], etc.` returned with each pass? The challenge I'm facing is comparing datetimes between multiple rows (my members) for each column (item1 - item10).

The current counter limits the items to 12, but does not take into account the datetimes...

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

  if($row["item1"]!="0000-00-00 00:00:00"){ // if datetime is set
    $item1cnt++;                            // add one to counter
    if($item1cnt > 12){                     // if counter is greater than 12
      $row["item1"]="";                     // itemx = ""
    }else{                                  // if counter is less than 12
      $row["item1"]="item1";                // item = itemx
    }
  }else{                                    // if datetime is not set
      $row["item1"]="";                     // itemx = ""
   }

// repeat above for all 10 items


// part of member's listing used by jquery to filter services
$items[] = "<li class=\"services " . $row["item1"] . " " . $row["item2"] . " " . $row["item3"] . " " . $row["item4"] . " " . $row["item5"] . " " . $row["item6"] . " " . $row["item7"] . " " . $row["item8"] . " " . $row["item9"] . " " . $row["item10"] . "\">";

  }

//an example situation for listings...the first twelve list their services
<li class="services item1 item2 item3 item4       item6 item7 item8 item9 item10">
<li class="services item1 item2 item3 item4 item5 item6 item7 item8 item9 item10">
<li class="services item1 item2 item3 item4 item5 item6 item7 item8 item9 item10">
<li class="services item1 item2 item3 item4 item5 item6 item7 item8 item9 item10">
<li class="services item1 item2 item3 item4 item5 item6 item7 item8 item9 item10">
<li class="services item1 item2 item3 item4 item5 item6 item7 item8 item9 item10">
<li class="services item1 item2 item3 item4 item5 item6 item7 item8 item9 item10">
<li class="services item1 item2 item3 item4 item5 item6 item7 item8 item9 item10">
<li class="services item1 item2 item3 item4 item5 item6 item7 item8 item9 item10">
<li class="services item1 item2 item3 item4 item5 item6 item7 item8 item9 item10">
<li class="services item1 item2 item3 item4 item5 item6 item7 item8 item9 item10">
<li class="services item1 item2 item3 item4 item5 item6 item7 item8 item9 item10">

//then another lists for all 10 services(items) but only item5 is available. The
 current code accomplishes this.
<li class="services                         item5                               ">
```

However, if the first member decides to offer `item5`, it will push the new guy off. So I need to use datetime to establish rank.

**Solution**

My `sql` query now uses `LEFT JOIN` and `LIMIT` for each of the items. @DarkSide provided the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225045/working-with-oldest-datetimes-for-multiple-columns)

Comment: can you elaborate on MYSQLi query? Maybe there is a better way, because string of concatenated datetimes does not feel right

Comment: Here is [my attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225045/working-with-oldest-datetimes-for-multiple-columns) using MYSQLi

Comment: And a good example of what I'm trying to accomplish is found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775752/order-and-limit-values-from-multiple-columns). Note: I actually need to keep the oldest 12, and replace the remaining datetimes, but shortened it to two for simplicity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have good SQL query for what you are trying to accomplish in
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24225215/350021

But here is the answer for your current question:

```
function transformItems($items, $preserve) {
    $items = array_map('rtrim', str_split($items, 20));
    asort($items);
    array_walk($items, function(&$val, $key, &$i) {
        if (--$i < 0) {
            $val = 'new';
        }
    }, $preserve);
    ksort($items);
    return implode(' ', $items);
}

// sample usage
$row["item"] = "2014-01-01 00:00:00 2014-04-04 00:00:00 2014-02-02 00:00:00 2014-03-03 00:00:00";
$row['item'] = transformItems($row['item'], 2);
// result: "2014-01-01 00:00:00 new 2014-02-02 00:00:00 new"
```

Comment: Thanks for the compliment! Please see my updated question. If your answer still applies, where/how do I work it into the code?

Comment: How do you determine the seniority? If the 1st guy starts offering item5 again where do you take the datetime from?

Comment: The members can login to select/deselect services for their listing at any time. For the services they select, the current datetime is inserted into each respective column for their row in the db. If they unselect a service, the datetime for that service is reset to 0000-00-00 00:00:00. They can make changes at any time. In short, datetimes are inserted, or reset to default as each member changes their offered services.

Comment: Thank you @Imre L. Your answer does what I originally asked, so I accepted your answer. I edited my original post with a link to the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try to convert the date to timestamp (SQL):

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE)
```

or php:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $unixTimestamp);
```

then compare to:

```
mktime(0) - 48*60*60
```